# Automate EC2 setup with secure parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, user-data

My question is quite oblique and generalised but I'm hoping for your ideas.
I want to automate a creation of EC2 instance including complete installation and configuration of a web application.
For this I need to to set up SSL keys, access keys and etc' on the server in the process.
The server is purposed for production and people who should not have access to some of these details/parameters will have shell access with unprivileged user.

- If I'm to set the secret parameters in the "user-data" anyone can extract them with `$ curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data`
- If I'm to put all secret stuff in secure S3 and give the instance a role to access it, unprivileged users can still cp/get from this bucket.
- I use Chef local-mode/chef-solo/chef zero for part of the setup - but my repository is also accessibly by people who shouldn't have access to some of this information.

I've thought of the clearly perverted idea of creating a policy allowing access to the secret bucket from the instance and then changing the policy as the last part of the user-data script. But I'm sure there is less insane way to do this.

Any ideas? I couldn't find anything on this in AWS docs...

Comment: Can you edit your question to much straightforward manners?  Use a simple,  I want to allow XXXX , deny access on YYY.  Bare with me as I am pretty confusing with the point say "if I so and so, Xxx can do yyy".

Answer (score 1):

You could encrypt the user data, decrypt it at boot time to provision the host, then remove the private key. I have a [blog post](https://whaletech.co/2015/02/25/securing-ec2-user-data.html) about this, but to summarize:

1. Create a public private keypair using something like this: `$ openssl req -nodes -x509 -days 10000 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout private.key -out public.crt -subj '/'`
2. Create an AMI, including the private key somewhere on the filesystem
3. Launch your instance and encrypt the user data using the public key
4. At the end of the provisioning script, remove the private key from the filesystem so that the user data can't be decrypted again

Any future instances launched from the AMI of course will have the private key, so you need to ensure no other users can create an instance.

Comment: This is a good idea, but I should have mentioned I also need to avoid dependency on custom AMI.

Comment: In that case, generate the key pair, put the private key in S3, download it at boot time, decrypt the user data, delete the private key from the local filesystem and from S3.